# What is the meaning of these lines in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
class Demo extends CI_Controller
{
  function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
  }
}
```

Comment: Its a simple Controller, inherited from base controller. What is your question ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

Comment: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#constructors

Comment: Am I the only one, that thinks this is not a serious question ?

Answer (score 5):

Demo class's constructor is calling its parent class's constructor which in this case is CI_Controller

Answer (score 3):

class `Demo` is extending the `CI_Controller`.

So all the public properties of `CI_Controller` can be overridden by class `Demo`.

`function __construct()` means that `constructor` if the class `Demo`.

In the `function __construct()`, `parent::__construct()` means that in the constructor, we are also calling the constructor of the parent class.